# Sharepoint 2007 Mysite only for specific user group

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

This might be simple or impossible ;-) 
Is there a way to restrict the Mysite usage to only a specific group in  Moss 07 so that only this groups has personal sites?

thanks in advance

Ren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're trying to archive is possible. Go to the Central Administration and open the Shared Service Provider for your web application.

There you have to select the entry "Personalization services permissions". On the next page you'll see a list where you could allow or deny certain functionality to certain groups. There you could define who's allowed to create a MySite and who's not.

[MSDN Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263073.aspx#section3)

Comment: ahh there it is .. thanks a lot 
btw it´s "Berechtigungen verwalten: Rechte für gemeinsame Dienste" ;-)